# Flexbox child is growing outside its parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use flexbox all of the time, but for some reason, this has had me scratching my head for a couple of days.

What I'm looking for is the cyan-colored area to be XY-scrollable (.scrollable), with the magenta (.tab-content) padding around it.

The lowest item that seems to have it together is the blue (.panels) div, which knows it should be window width and 200px high.  Then the flex child .body just grows off of the screen.

It seems like the problem is that .body can't figure out how wide the parent .panels is.  I've never had an issue like this, and I'm pretty sure it revolves around not being able to wrap the text in the cyan table, but I have to have those as individual lines.

**Chrome 48 (version mandated):**
[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.detail {} .panels {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.header {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.body {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.tabs {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.tab-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: magenta;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.formatted-text {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="detail">
  <div class="panels">
    <div class="header">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="tabs">Tabs</div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="scrollable">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Codepen here:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjvWzR

Comment: Set the overflow on the parent container to scroll or auto or hidden.

Comment: @Blunderfest that makes the magenta area vertically scrollable, and does not affect it growing off of the side of the screen

Comment: You need to specify the overflow for each of the containers, if I just put overflow-hidden on your .panels class, all the overflow is clipped. Putting it on each layer on the way down is a good bet.

Comment: Your html structure is difficult for me to read. But this is something like what you need : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGwWMR

Comment: @Blunderfest Again, you're scrolling the magenta area and not the cyan

Comment: Perhaps related to this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to solve that with `position: absolute`, like this

```
.scrollable {
  background-color: cyan;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  top:1rem; 
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;  
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.detail {}

.panels {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.body {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.tabs {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.tab-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: magenta;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.scrollable {
  background-color: cyan;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  top:1rem; 
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;  
}

.formatted-text {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="detail">
  <div class="panels">
    <div class="header">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="tabs">Tabs</div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="scrollable">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!  I tried messing around with absolute/relative positioning, but I think I was applying it to elements too high up the chain..  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into an .html file and tested it out and it is working as you are expecting.  My guess is your issues are caused by other css passed down from some parent components on your page.

Here is the combination of your css and html above that I ran to get the successful result:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .detail {} .panels {
          background-color: blue;
          display: flex;
          max-height: 200px;
        }
        .header {
          background-color: red;
          margin-right: 1rem;
          flex-shrink: 0;
        }
        .body {
          background-color: green;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          flex: 1;
        }
        .tabs {
          flex-shrink: 0;
        }
        .tab-content {
          flex: 1;
          background-color: magenta;
          padding: 1rem;
        }
        .scrollable {
          overflow: auto;
          background-color: cyan;
        }
        .formatted-text {
          white-space: pre;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="detail">
      <div class="panels">
        <div class="header">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Field</td>
              <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Field</td>
              <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Field</td>
              <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Field</td>
              <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
          <div class="tabs">Tabs</div>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="scrollable">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td class="formatted-text">THIS IS SOME REALLY, REALLY LONG TEXT THAT REPRESENTS FIXED-WIDTH FILE OUTPUT, SO IT WILL BE IN A MONO FONT AND CANNOT BREAK PER LINE. EACH LINE IS 300 BYTES LONG.</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```